# Does $(A\otimes B)^{-1}=(A\otimes B)^{\dagger}$ imply $A$ and $B$ unitary?

Tags: tensor-products, kronecker-product

I know we can distribute Hermitian conjugation and 'Inverses' w.r.t the Kronecker product, i.e:

$$(A\otimes B)^{-1}=(A\otimes B)^{\dagger} \leftrightarrow(A^{-1}\otimes B^{-1})=(A^{\dagger}\otimes B^{\dagger}).$$

but, does this imply $A^{-1}=A^{\dagger}$ and $B^{-1}=B^{\dagger}$? That is my question.

Comment: Almost true, but not quite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A = 2I$ and $B=\frac 12I$ with  $I$ being the identity matrix. Then
$$
A\otimes B= I\implies 
(A\otimes B)^{-1} = I  = (A\otimes B)^{\dagger}
$$
but $A^{-1} \ne A = A^{\dagger}$

---

In general, if $X\otimes Y\ne 0$, you have that
$$
X\otimes Y = M\otimes N \iff X=cM,\,\, Y=c^{-1}N
$$
with $c\ne 0$. In your case, you can say that
$$
A^{-1}=cA^\dagger,\,\, B^{-1}=c^{-1}B^{\dagger}
$$
for a common $c$.

Comment: Right. That's a super clear way to think about it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @JuanC97 see also the edit